# how to set up a multi-level git workflow

Tags: git

We're in the process of transitioning from svn to git, and one of the motivations is to set up a local cache repo in one of our remote offices so that the devs there don’t need to push and pull from the main repo over a slow network the whole time.

So the basic process will be that localCache will fetch from the main repo periodically, and devs will fetch from localCache. Devs will then push to localCache and once they have finished a feature, they will push from localCache to main.

localCache is configured as --mirror

This seems to work OK except when I want to push changes from localCache when there are also changes from main on the same branch. If I fetch from main before pushing, the branch from main overwrites what has just been pushed from the devs; if I push to main before fetching, the branch from localCache overwrites main. In both cases git gives me a “forced update” message even though I’m not specifying --force.

This makes me think I’m going about it the wrong way. I’m sure this is the kind of thing git should be good at, but it doesn’t seem a smooth workflow to me. In the “distributed workflows” section of the git book, all the workflows they describe have the developers always pulling from “main” but that’s exactly what I’m trying to avoid.

Comment: People should only push to localCache, why are there changes to main? also, I am pretty sure git doesn't "overwrite" things easily. Would you mind describing the setup and the workflow a little bit more?

Comment: @coredump - the reason there are other changes to main is that not all developers are using the localCache. when I say overwritten I mean the branch pointer is overwritten; no files are lost as such but the commits become inaccessible. The next time a dev tries to pull from whichever repo (main or localCache) has had the branch pointer overwritten, he has to do a merge which merges in the inaccessible changes. I think the essence of the problem is that I'd like to do this merge in localCache at the point of pushing to main, but localCache has to be a mirror clone and this can't support merges

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want what is called a "triangular workflow".  NOTE: This is not quite what you are asking for, but I have had it work well in practice.  The reason it works well is that pushes tend to be small and infrequent, while clones and fetches are large and frequent.

Here is an example of triangular workflow that assumes you are using Git 2.0 or later, and ssh authentication:

```
$ git clone ssh://localoffice.company.com/repos/project
$ cd project
$ git remote add hq ssh://companyhq.company.com/repos/project
$ git config remote.pushdefault hq
```

Now, as I work in `project`, every `git fetch` fetches from `localoffice.company.com/repos/project`, and `git push` pushes to `companyhq.company.com/repos/project`.  Details are below.

---

Triangular workflow, illustrated:

```
definitive-source
      /    ^
     /      \
    v        \
 cache ---> work
```

The cache is your local mirror, and the definitive-source is the master from which the cache is updated.  There is a minor headache in keeping the local caches "sufficiently up to date" without putting a lot of strain on the networks (VPNs with slow links, typically).

Git supports triangular workflow "out of the box" since Git version 1.8.3, via configuration variables `remote.pushDefault` and `branch.branch.pushDefault`.  This does require a slight bit of configuration done by, or on behalf of, each person doing work: they must `git clone` from the cache so that their `origin` URL points to the cache mirror, but configure the pushes to go to a different remote and hence different URL (through either the default remote for pushing, or the URL per-branch).

(Then they must push without naming a remote, or, if they do name a remote, name the definitive source.)

(In a previous job, long ago—before Git version 1.8 even existed—I had a hand in setting up the local mirrors to serve via `git://` protocol, but all pushes went via `ssh://`.  We had some custom wrapper scripts that did all this, rather than using these configuration variables, which did not exist then.)

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts torek. The vision I had was that the teams would use the localCache to share their work with each other while working on a story, and then they would clean up/squash the commit history before pushing back to main. I gather it's considered a bad idea to rewrite commit history after pushing to main, so I was trying to avoid that.

Comment: The "do/don't rewrite history" is really a matter of coordination. Any kind of rewrite really involves copying and then abandoning previous commits. If you're the *only person* (with just one repository involved) with replacement commits, no one else can get confused and accidentally use or reintroduce the old, abandoned commits. If *multiple people and/or repositories* are involved, they must all coordinate. If they *will* coordinate, it doesn't matter which repositories are treated this way, and if they *won't*, it ... doesn't matter which repositories are treated this way. :-)

Comment: That said (I ran out of room), it's worth noting that to carry out this coordination, it helps to know which repositories and/or branch-names are being treated this way. You can (attempt to) do this by specific repository, but I think you will see better results, in the long run, by doing this by specific branch names and/or name-patterns. For instance (off the top of my head) perhaps branches named `rewdev/foo` are susceptible to rewrite/rewind, while `dev/foo` are forward-development-only, so if you're going to do rewrites you can only push them to `rewdev/*`.